# The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later. FancyBox error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

Iam using FancyBox on Rails 3 application. I want to get popup of multiple images like gallery. All images are aviable on server.

My code so far:

```
            <a class="fancybox"   title=""><%=  image_tag('s_1.jpg',:width=>100) %></a>
            <a class="fancybox"   title=""><%= image_tag('s_2.jpg',:width=>100) %></a>
            <a class="fancybox"  title=""><%= image_tag('s_3.jpg',:width=>100) %></a>
            <a class="fancybox"   title=""><%= image_tag('s_4.jpg',:width=>100) %></a>
            <a class="fancybox"   title=""><%= image_tag('s_5.jpg',:width=>100) %></a>
```

**My application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "iframe",
        width : 380, // or whatever
        height: 280
    }).trigger("click");
});
```

Error that I get is

```
The requested content cannot be loaded.
```

Tried to change application code to this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
```

Then when I clicked on images they changed their position and disapiered  at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the path to image in the href of anchor tag having class "fancybox"

```
<a class="fancybox" href="<%=image_tag('s_1.jpg',:width=>100) %>" title=""><%= image_tag('s_2.jpg',:width=>100) %></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an `<a>` without `href` attribute. Fancybox needs a href attr to connect to.

What you probably want is: 
`<a class="fancybox" href="PATH_TO_THE_LARGE_IMG" title=""><img ../></a>`

Example:

`<a class="fancybox" href="http://placehold.it/800x600/ff0/0f0" title="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/ff0/0f0" alt="img" />
 </a>`

### EDIT:

If you want to create a gallery with multiple images (with next & prev buttons) try adding attribute `rel` to all the anchors in that group

example `<a class="fancybox" href="..." title="" rel="gal-1">..</a>`